# Why is Kotlin function name being mangled when passing Duration

Tags: kotlin

In my current Android application im investigating the use of Duration with coroutine delay function as follows:-

```
class WorkerTwo(private val context: Context, private val params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    @ExperimentalTime
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        (0..100 step 30).forEach {
            setProgress(workDataOf(PROGRESS to it))

            delay(Duration.Companion.seconds(1L)) // CRASH HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }

        Result.success()
    }
}
```

However when I install and run my application it crashes as follows

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method delay-p9JZ4hM(JLkotlin/coroutines/Continuation;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lkotlinx/coroutines/DelayKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlinx.coroutines.DelayKt' appears in /data/app/org.research.development.versiononefive-nC90emPcnKpqBIJrwhWkgQ==/base.apk)
        at org.research.development.versiononefive.WorkerTwo$doWork$2.invokeSuspend(WorkerTwo.kt:19)
```

The `delay` method name is being mangled to `delay-p9JZ4hM`, why is this occurring?

UPDATE

I fixed this by adding this to my gradle file

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha03"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0-alpha03"

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0-RC"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0-RC"
```

and refactoring the delay function call like this:-

```
delay(Duration.seconds(1L)) // CRASH HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Comment: The mangled `delay(Duration)` methods in coroutines have changed between Kotlin 1.4.x and Kotlin 1.5 due to the underlying change in the backing field type of Duration (from Double to Long). For this to work, you need to either compile with Kotlin 1.5.0 AND with coroutines >= 1.5.0-RC, or use a previous version of coroutines and Kotlin 1.4.x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Duration` is a an *inline class* (value class in Kotlin 1.5+).

That means that in the JVM there is no `Duration` class at all.  It's represented by a `Double` (`Long` in 1.5+) with no wrapper.

When you write a method that takes an inline class as a parameter, Kotlin mangles the name so that it doesn't have the same signature as an overload that takes the underlying value, i.e., so that you can have both `delay(Duration)` and `delay(Double)` even though in the JVM the parameter types are the same.

About your error:

As mentioned, inline classes change to value classes in Kotlin 1.5, and there is also a new feature that allows explicitly setting the JVM name of a method.

The likely cause of your error is that you are compiling Kotlin 1.5 and running with libraries from an older version, or vice-versa, and the mangled name of `delay` is different in one vs the other.  Also, the underlying type of `Duration` has changed, so even if the names matched you wouldn't be able to call the method.

Comment: what's the feature that allows the name of the method to be manually set? I tried `@JvmName()`, but it doesn't seem to be accepted for functions.

Comment: `@JvmName` is the one I was talking about.  I don't think there is one for functions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see Duration.Companion.seconds method, maybe because I have another Kotlin version.
But you can use duration like here:

```
delay(1.seconds)
```

Also, you can use time milliseconds:

```
delay(1000L)
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt spot code complete had added Companion.

Comment: FYI the `Int.seconds` extensions have been deprecated in Kotlin 1.5, and the corresponding companion object factory methods were added (`Duration.seconds(1)`).